# Shopping cart doesn't update (unless I refresh page)

Tags: prestashop

When I click 'Add to Cart' for a product, the cart doesn't update (unless you refresh the page). I've set the freeshippingtranslation to zero (see code below) but still not updating.

Can anyone help with this issue please? I use Prestashop 1.5.5 and my site is www.ayereadytshirts.com

if (parseFloat(jsonData.shippingCostFloat) > 0 || jsonData.nbTotalProducts < 1) $('.ajax_cart_shipping_cost').text(jsonData.shippingCost);

```
else if (typeof(freeShippingTranslation) != '0') 

    $('.ajax_cart_shipping_cost').html(freeShippingTranslation);
```

Answer (score 1):

`freeShippingTranslation` is not defined

In comparsion you should use instead of

`else if (typeof(freeShippingTranslation) != '0')`

such a way

`else if (typeof freeShippingTranslation === undefined)`

Comment: Thanks @IvanHanak this has worked however when I add to cart it does not show the product anymore (unless refresh) Any ideas why?

Comment: for now, check your ajax-cart.js, according to the console, when adding a product to the cart, there is undefined `freeShippingTranslation ` on line 472

Comment: thanks.  Do you know how to fix Uncaught ReferenceError: freeProductTranslation is not defined? in ajax-cart.js

Comment: It is probably undefined or something, I am not aware, how do you set your variabled. All times, you need to revise your code dude, I took a closer look in console and you have there a couple of errors. (console in firefox and chrome through F12)